# C programming using eclipse

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile

I am new to eclipse using for C programming in Ubuntu. 
When I run a c program it is displaying `Launch failed binary not found` even after installing g++.

I installed g++ using following command

`sudo apt-get install g++`

second question is how to create `makefile` and how it is useful ?

Comment: make sure eclipse is setup to use g++ as the run / debug settings. A makefile is a script to speed up creation of the program instead of manually typing in all the linked libraries, files, and output files.

Comment: could you tell me how to setup g++ as run/debug settings

Comment: i basically mean setting up CDT with the desired compiler in the build settings, then build it, then run it.

Comment: Concerning makefile: you'd better [read the manual first](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html) and then look at examples in small projects (you need ones not driven by libtool, e.g. not `Makefile.am`).

Comment: @colwinter: would you let me know how to set desired compiler to CDT

Answer (score 2):

Remember to build your project first. The first time I used Eclipse+CDT I got the same error: I was trying to run the project without building it.

Answer (score 1):

1. install `build-essential` and `eclipse-cdt`. (you probably need `gcc`, not `g++`)
2. A `Makefile` is a file that declares the order of building. it's very useful in large programs. (if you have just one .c file, don't use make)

Comment: i have installed cdt in eclipse and i previously used command prompt for executing c through gcc, so i think i dont need to install it again